# Oпределение id блока jQuery

Tags: jquery

Скажите пожалуйста как на jquery определить id div,

```
<div class="elem" id='elem1'>
    <input type="button" class="delete" value="1">
</div>
<div class="elem" id='elem2'>
    <input type="button" class="delete" value="2">
</div>
<div class="elem" id='elem3'>
    <input type="button" class="delete" value="3">
</div>
```

допустим есть такие блоки, когда нажимаем кнопка получить id div на котором этот кнопка.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим можно искать по одинаковому классу
$(".elem").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id')); });

Comment: Так же можно добавить в каждые элемент

оnClick="get_id(this. id);"
функцией get_id делать что душе угодно

Comment: А извиняюсь, тут при нажатие на кнопку.

Comment: Тут зависит от ситуации, для чего нужны эти кнопочки.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод closest(). [Справка](http://jquery-docs.ru/traversing/closest/)

Comment: Или **parent()**. А вот справка - мягко говоря, фуфло; другим не показывайте и сами забудьте. Если уж не на [официальном сайте](http://api.jquery.com/) (*что настоятельно рекомендую*), то [на крайний случай тут](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/).

Comment: Ну раньше мне казалось, что это был перевод официального сайта